# Verifying which SMTP server software is used by remote server

Tags: shell-script, smtp, telnet

I am trying to catalog which smtp servers are used in an heterogenous pool of servers, and so far I was doing :

```
echo "HELO localhost"  | telnet localhost 25 2>/dev/null | grep 220
#process the output of command
```

My problem is the server doesn't always have time to answer "220 ..." before the socket is closed.

So I'm looking of a relatively short, bash-based script that would be a bit more reliable. I couldn't find an easy way to make the command wait a few seconds before closing the TCP connection.

I tried `expect` but i can't get it to work, and that requires an external file, which doesn't really fit in my auditing suite, and I can't be sure to have it available on all servers.

Any simple ideas ?

**EDIT : versions** (yep, old, I know):

- bash-2.05b-41.7
- coreutils-4.5.3-28.1
- linux-2.4.21

Comment: Just ping 127.0.0.1 for a few packets, works great as an easy pause. :)

Comment: I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bob on the chat suggested to use a subshell, including sleep between two echoes.

This works like a charm :

```
( echo "EHLO `hostname`"; sleep 1; echo "QUIT" ) | telnet `hostname` 25
```

I can `grep 220` now, and i'm quite sure to get the answer within the one second scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`nmap(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) fingerprinting capabilities, from the manpage:

```
SERVICE/VERSION DETECTION:
-sV: Probe open ports to determine service/version info
```

An example:

```
$ nmap -sV some.mail.server.biz -p 25

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-09-17 17:50 CEST
    Nmap scan report for some.mail.server.biz (10.0.0.135)
Host is up (0.0052s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
25/tcp open  smtp    MailEnable smptd 7.08--7.08
Service Info: Host: some.domain.com; OS: Windows; CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.67 seconds
```

I don't know if it is useful for you, but the output uses [CPE](http://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm).

Comment: Unfortunatly, `nmap` isn't available on most machines, and I can't install more softwares for this "project" needs'.

Comment: You are not supposed to install it on every machine, you can perform the scan remotely from a single remote box with a modern operating system.

Comment: Furthermore, you can scan a whole subnet replacing the hostname with a target specified in CIDR notation.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind, but that doesn't fit my auditing process which implies running scripts on each machine. I could keep it as a workaround though, thanks.